# Comparing two date columns of a datagridview and columns may contain empty date

Tags: c#

I want to compare two columns of datagridview which contains dates in format "DD-MM-YYYY".

I used this code:

```
var d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DueDate"].Value);
var d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value);

if(d1 <= d2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Late Payment");
}
```

I have following two date columns in the datagridview. As row # 2 and 3 are empty for `PaymentDate` column, my code throws an exception

> String was not recognized as a valid datetime

for row # 2 and 3

```
DueDate         PaymentDate
----------------------------    
27-03-2018      12-03-2018
09-02-2018       
21-09-2018
17-05-2018      22-04-2018
```

Please tell me the exact code to resolve the issue

Comment: The problem is not related to comparison. It's related to convert the string to datetime. Kindly do some research in this direction and update here if help required.

Comment: Use TryParse instead of convert.

Comment: DateTime v3 ;
                DateTime v4;       
                                                                                                                      var d1 = DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DueDate"].Value.ToString(),out v3);
                                                 var d2 = DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value.ToString(), out v4);                                                                                                                                         Null reference exception

Comment: @shakeelahmad If you are getting a null reference exception is because `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DueDate"].Value` is resolving to null.  You need to protect against that.  Check if its null before calling `.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dueDate = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DueDate"].Value != null
    ? dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DueDate"].Value.ToString()
    : string.Empty;

var paymentDate = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value != null
    ? dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value.ToString()
    : string.Empty;

DateTime d1;
DateTime d2;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(dueDate, out d1) || !DateTime.TryParse(paymentDate, out d2))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Period"); //Here you can show a message or simply bypass
    return;
}

if (d1 <= d2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Late Payment");
}
```